# Can we execute script file against database using fluent Nhibernate?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I want to execute script file on my database using fluent nhibernate. Can you tell me how can i achieve this?
 I have a file say "myScript.sql" on my c drive, which i want to execute against my **oracle** database.

Thanks in advance,
Ashish

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Comment: @Andread No it doesn't - the question is specifically about programmatically executing a script, using Fluent NHibernate

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420244/nhibernate-and-sql-scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't execute anything using Fluent - it's simply a convenient way of generating mappings for NHibernate. You can execute a SQL script using NHibernate as a [named query](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/querysql.html) if it is known up front and compiled into the mappings.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I mean "You can execute a SQL script using NHibernate as a named query" how can i do this?

Comment: Check the link I've just added in the answer, particularly sec 13.3

Answer (score 0):

You can use this open source tool for schema management:([+](http://nst.codeplex.com/))