# Fluent Nhibernate and sql script

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, sql-scripts

I want to execute a script with variables in order to create a new database.
At first, i tried with command line but i want to execute the script from another server but i have errors about access rights.

Is it possible to execute a SQL script with fluent nhibernate in the application code?

I've found an answer on that link but it doesn't execute the script, it loads queries.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420244/nhibernate-and-sql-scripts)

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

JUST a note: Fluent NHibernate is just a third party library for mapping. To execute script you need *just* NHibernate.

And in fact, the answer you've found, is the answer. The point of WRITE scripts is to call `ExecuteUpdate()` at the end

```
var query = session.CreateSQLQuery("your sql to string with INSERT, UPDATE...");
// that will execute that all
query.ExecuteUpdate();
```